# swift 5 - xcode 10.2 update problem. gettin to much warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I updated Xcode to 10.2 , and take a some problems. My pods give a Swift compiler Warning. This warning is  `Unexpected version number in 'available' attribute for non-specific platform '*'` The warning number is 140, I am jr. sorry for this question but maybe someone help me.
And My swift language Version is - Swift 5

Comment: change swift version to 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your Pods target (left) and then in 'Build settings' search for SWIFT_VERSION.

There you can set it to 5.0.

YOu should also update your Pods and check if they are actually available for Swift5 (check their github page)

[image: See here]

Answer (score 0):

You must change target's swift version to 4.2 0r 4.0 from 5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking Swift version try this:

```
@available(swift, obsoleted:3.0, message:"<Your message>")
```

This method silenced my warnings, You can read more [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-available-to-deprecate-old-apis)